# Why isn't the button clickable in the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have a JTable which has several rows, and one button at each row. Somehow I believe the button is not clickable.

Here is my code:

```
public class JTableJButton {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button;
    JTable table;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public JTableJButton(){
        frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        panel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Remove");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Pressed");
            }
        });

        String col[] = {"number", "name#", "button"};
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);

        Object[] data1 = {"1", "name1", button};
        tableModel.addRow(data1);

        Object[] data2 = {"2", "name2", button};
        tableModel.addRow(data2);

        Object[] data3 = {"3", "name3", button};
        tableModel.addRow(data3);


        table = new JTable(tableModel){
         @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                //all cells false
                return false;
            }
        };


        TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
        table.getColumn("button").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);

        TableCellEditor editor = new myEditor();
        table.getColumn("button").setCellEditor(editor);

        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new JTableJButton();
    }


    private static class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {        
        @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JButton button = (JButton)value;
            return button;  
        }
    }
```

So is there any idea to make the button working and make it to do functions like removing the selected row and so on??

**EDIT:** Based on provided link in the coments, I noticed I need to create a CellEditor class, as below:

```
public class myEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
                         implements TableCellEditor,
                                    ActionListener {

        private Object editorValue;


        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editorValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.print("HI");
        }

    }
```

But I am still lost and I do not understand the procedure that these method make the button working. I read [How to Use Tables: Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), but still cant figure out what data must be in the method base on my case. Can anyone provide any example just to give me idea how it is working?

Comment: The button is only used to paint the cell (hence the name `TableCellRenderer`) - it's not a real button.  To make this work, you also need to have a `TableCellEditor`.  It's been too long for me since I've used Swing to provide more details, but perhaps armed with this knowledge you'll be able to search for specifically.

Comment: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/ perhaps.

Comment: [Swing Tutorial: Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: @GregKopff, Thanks for the comments. I made some progress but still coulndnt get it working. Can you please check the edited question? Thanks